# Azure Logic App -Can this Custom RBAC rule be created?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, serverless, rbac, azure-rbac

Can a Azure RBAC custom rule be set up so that the Role can ONLY Resubmit an earlier  Logic App Run BUT not Modify the workflow via Designer oor otherwise ?

Comment: what is resubmit the logic?

Comment: Updated the Q...acually meant the Resubmission of an earlier Logic App run

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really good at logic apps, but here's how you can get the list of possible rbac rules:

```
Get-AzProviderOperation -OperationSearchString 'microsoft.logic/*' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty operation | Sort-Object
```

I suppose, if you only give permission to `Microsoft.Logic/workflows/runs/*` that wouldnt allow the person to modify them, as that (most likely) requires `Microsoft.Logic/workflows/write`. You would also need to give read permissions.

```
Microsoft.Logic/workflows/run/action
Microsoft.Logic/workflows/runs/actions/listExpressionTraces/action
Microsoft.Logic/workflows/runs/actions/read
Microsoft.Logic/workflows/runs/actions/repetitions/listExpressionTraces/action
Microsoft.Logic/workflows/runs/actions/repetitions/read
Microsoft.Logic/workflows/runs/actions/repetitions/requestHistories/read
Microsoft.Logic/workflows/runs/actions/requestHistories/read
Microsoft.Logic/workflows/runs/actions/scoperepetitions/read
Microsoft.Logic/workflows/runs/cancel/action
Microsoft.Logic/workflows/runs/delete
Microsoft.Logic/workflows/runs/operations/read
Microsoft.Logic/workflows/runs/read
```